# I am trying to reset selected file with input tag file type in Angular 9/10,i googled and found the solution,but its not working though

Tags: typescript, angular9

**component.ts**

```
  @ViewChild("editphoto",{static:false}) editphoto: ElementRef;

removePhoto(){

this.editphoto.nativeElement.value = '';

}



uploadEditFile(event) {

const file = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
this.editPostForm.patchValue({
  image: file,
});
this.editPostForm.get("image").updateValueAndValidity();
// File Preview
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = () => {
  this.showCloseButton = true;
  this.imageURL = reader.result as string;
};
reader.readAsDataURL(file);


 }
```

component.html

```
 <input #editphoto type="file" class="form-control" accept="image/*" (change)="uploadEditFile($event)"/>

<button click="removePhoto()">reset photo</button>
```

**I am getting an error saying  VM6770 vendor.js:36534 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined** Please do help me

Comment: use `(click)=""` instead of `click=""`, hope it will work.

Comment: Yes i tried,it's showing the same error message

Comment: could you please update your whole code, I'm getting error from `f.image.errors`,  `editPostForm` etc.

Comment: I'm getting this error when i click on remove photo button,i don't think `f.image.errors,editPostForm `.etc is a concern,you can see i removed the class

Comment: @HarishS for its working (ur example) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zowcp6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thanks @LashanFernando its working for me!!